# Find the number of times K appears in any 4 item subset of T

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given the set *T* of all *K*

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

Let *N* be 4.
There can be produced 126 combinations of *N* items, as subsets *S*.

Every *K* has an equal probability of being a member of any set. In this particular case, we find the probability to be 44.444444%, that any *K* is a member of any *S* (9 will appear in 56 sets, if all possible subsets of length 4 from *T* are considered).

As the size of the *T* increases, the probability decreases that any given *K* will be found in a subset *S*. How can I represent the chance the probability that a *K* will be found for sets *T* of any size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solve the problem by counting, as you did, and then in another way.

We stick to subsets of size $4$, but let the size of $T$ be $n$. There are $\binom{n}{4}$ four-element subsets of $T$. If $t$ is a particular element of $T$, to make a set of $4$ elements containing $t$, we must choose the $3$ companions of $t$. This can be done in $\binom{n-1}{3}$ ways.

So our required probability is $\frac{\binom{n-1}{3}}{\binom{n}{4}}$.  It is not hard to verify by manipulation of factorials that $\binom{n}{4}=\frac{n}{4}\binom{n-1}{3}$, so our probability is $\frac{4}{n}$.

The same reasoning shows that if we choose subsets of size $k$, then the probability that a particular element is in the chosen set is $\frac{k}{n}$.

**Another way:** For concreteness we work with $4$-element subsets. A lottery sells $n$ distinctly numbered tickets, and there is only one prize. You buy $4$ tickets. The probability you hold the winning number is $\frac{4}{n}$.

Comment: I got the 4/n part, but it was the incremental probabilities that I was after. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.